# How do I use a Cell value inside of a string?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following in my Google Sheet to pull number of views from a YouTube page:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1D8XIIvYS0","//div[@class='watch-view-count']")
```

I'd like to split out the YouTube ID into a different column and do the following where B2 is the cell with the value 'i1D8XIIvYS0'

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2","//div[@class='watch-view-count']")
```

How do I escape 'B2' so that the value is used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="&B2,"//div[@class='watch-view-count']")
```

If your referencing b2 you just need to remove the quote from after it to in front of it and use the `&` to join the value with the string

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: Great, the works perfectly. So basically you terminate the string and use the ampersand to tell Sheets that there will be a cell designation.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="& B2 &"","//div[@class='watch-view-count']")
```

Comment: you have an extra `&` and quotes in your formula after b2